# The time after some time

Tags: code-golf

For this challenge, we are writing the time in the following form: `hh:mm:ss`

Some examples:

> `12:34:08`
>
> `06:05:30`
>
> `23:59:00`

The challenge is to output the time after an amount of *hours*, *minutes* and *seconds* have elapsed, with as starting time `00:00:00`. You can compare this with a timer that started at `00:00:00`.

Here is an example of inputs (using **STDIN**) and outputs:

```
Input: 1h20m5s
Output: 01:20:05

Input: 0h100m0s
Output: 01:40:00
```

After 24 hours, the timer resets itself:

```
Input: 25h0m0s
Output: 01:00:00
```

The form of the input is always the same: `XhYmZs`, with `X` hours, `Y` minutes and `Z` seconds (assume that `X`, `Y` and `Z` are whole integers less than 100000 and never negative)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so least amount of bytes wins this challenge

Comment: Can we write functions?

Comment: @LegionMammal978, yes

Comment: "assume that X, Y and Z are whole integers less than 99999 and never negative" is 99999h99999m99999s a valid input?

Comment: @Cruncher, yes, that is a valid input

Comment: 99999 is not less than 99999.

Comment: @Luke, sorry you're right. I have corrected it in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## CJam, 34 bytes

```
leu~]2%60b86400%60b3Te[{s2Te[}%':*
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=reu~%5D2%2560b86400%2560b3Te%5B%22%2502d%22fe%25'%3A*&input=0h100m0s).

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby - <s>131</s> <s>115</s> <s>107</s> <s>97</s> 84 bytes

I'm still golfing it.

```
h,m,s=gets.split(/\w/).map &:to_i;$><<"#{(h+m/60+s/3600)%24}:#{(m+s/60)%60}:#{s%60}"
```

Thanks for @Doorknob for /\w/ inshead of /h|m|s/

Comment: You can split on a regex: `gets.tr('ms',?h).split(?h)` -> `gets.split(/\w/)`.

Comment: @Doorknob I've just rewritten it to regexes but yours is shorter. Thanks!

Comment: I give up on trying to compete. Mma is just too verbose.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Never give up ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>133</s> <s>116</s> <s>112</s> 111 bytes

```
IntegerString[(f=FromDigits)[f/@StringSplit[#,_?LetterQ],60]~Mod~86400~IntegerDigits~60,10,2]~StringRiffle~":"&
```

Answer (score 2):

### C <del>149</del> 112 bytes

[Test it here](https://ideone.com/3XPyFd)

```
main(h,m,s){scanf("%dh%dm%ds",&h,&m,&s);s+=h*3600+m*60;h=s/3600;m=s/60;printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",h%24,m%60,s%60);}
```

Credits to @Dennis for getting rid of a lot it.

Comment: `main(h,m,s){scanf("%dh%dm%ds",&h,&m,&s);s+=h*3600+m*60;m=s/60;h=m/60;printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",h%24,m%60,s%60);}` (110 bytes, reads from STDIN)

Comment: @Dennis thanks, forgot it didn't have to be a command line argument. The only thing that wasn't working for me was the declaration of the variables in the function argument list; I was getting compiler errors with that.

Comment: `h,m,s;main()` should be more portable. `main(h,m,s)` works with GCC ([link](http://ideone.com/2b6Ynq))

Comment: Ok, thanks. Got it down to 112.

Comment: `m=s/60;h=m/60;` ? After this you can get rid of the `s+=` too.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>138</s> 126 Bytes

Now I'm using regex, still quite long though..

```py
import re
a=input();b=map(int,re.split('h|m|s',a)[:-1])
s=b[0]*3600+b[1]*60+b[2]
print(':%02d'*3)[1:]%(s/3600%24,s/60%60,s%60)
```

Input should be in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 80 <del>88</del> <del>93</del> Bytes

```
<?=!$s=split(~¤—’¢,fgets(STDIN)),date(~·Å–ÅŒ,$s[0]*3600+$s[1]*60+$s[2]-date(Z));
```

(saved as ISO-8859-1)

Works only on PHP 5 because of deprecated `split` function. Assumes that notices are not shown.

#### How it works:

- `¤—’¢` is `"[hm]"` inverted and a valid constant name, PHP uses undefined constants as string (saves one character for the quotation marks)
- `·Å–ÅŒ` is the same for `"H:i:s"`
- Everything is a single short handed echo statement. `<?=x,y` outputs x and y. Using `!`, the result of the `$s` assignment gets converted to boolean and negated, then converted to string to output. `(string)false === ''`
- `split("[hm]", "XhYmZs")` splits the string to `[X,Y,Zs]`. Then, `3600*X+60*Y+Zs` is the number of seconds. PHP converts `Zs` to integer as `Z`
- We substract the timezone offset `date(Z)`, use this result as a timestamp and print its time part as "hours:minutes:seconds". In UTC (offset 0), the timestamp `0` is `1970/01/01 00:00:00`. Substracting the timezone offset normalizes the date as UTC without changing the actually used timezone (this saved 8 bytes for setting the timezone).
- Conveniently, 25 hours will result in 01:00:00 (on the next day).

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript 110 bytes

Where x is the input

```
x=x.split(/[hms]/).map(Number);for(z=2;z--;)x[z+1]-60&&(x[z]+=~~(x[z+1]/60));y=x[0]%24+":"+x[1]%60+":"+x[2]%60
```

I don't think this is the most efficient way

```
// How it works:
x=x.split(/[hms]/).map(Number);                // splitting the string into an array of numbers
for(z=2;z--;)x[z+1]-60&&(x[z]+=~~(x[z+1]/60)); // shifting excess of seconds to minutes, and then minutes to hours
y=x[0]%24+":"+x[1]%60+":"+x[2]%60              // putting them all together
```

Answer (score 1):

## AutoIt, 208 bytes

```
Func _($0)
$1=StringRegExp($0,"[0-9]+",3)
For $2=2 To 1 Step -1
If $1[$2]>59 Then
$1[$2]=Mod($1[$2],59)-1
$1[$2-1]+=1
EndIf
Next
Return StringFormat("%02u:%02u:%02u",$1[0]-($1[0]>23?24:0),$1[1],$1[2])
EndFunc
```

Too long. Test:

```
ConsoleWrite(_("1h20m5s") & @LF)
ConsoleWrite(_("0h100m0s") & @LF)
ConsoleWrite(_("25h0m0s") & @LF)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 40 bytes

```
j\:%L"%02d">3j+%ivM:z"\d+"1K60 86400^KTK
```

I'm still learning. [Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 84 (83 Bytes + 1)

Uses the overflow of seconds or minutes.

```
($h,$m,$s)=split/\D/;$h+=($m+=$s/60)/60;printf"%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d",$h%24,$m%60,$s%60
```

#### Test

```
$ echo 35:124:224s |perl -n 61736-time-after-some-time.pl
13:07:44
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBA (<strike>150</strike>149 bytes)

```
Function t(s)
x = Split(Replace(Replace(Replace(s, "s", ""), "m", " "), "h", " "))
t = Format(TimeSerial(x(0), x(1), x(2)), "HH:MM:SS")
End Function
```

Comment: Looks Good. VBA seems great for this task. If you use `msgbox` as output you can change to a `Sub` and save 2 bytes. You can Also Golf away all the unneeded white space around the `=` and after each `,` to knock it down around 134.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 97 bytes

```
x=>([h,m,s]=x.match(/\d+/g),[(+h+m/60|0)%24,(+m+s/60|0)%60,s%=60].map(a=>(a>9?'':'0')+a).join`:`)
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a Fiddle? Doesn't seem to work for me. I get `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: @GustvandeWal So far FireFox is the only browser to support [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so a fiddle won't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 84 Bytes

```
$a=$args-split'[hms]';"{0:HH:mm:ss}"-f(date 0).AddSeconds(3600*$a[0]+60*$a[1]+$a[2])
```

Splits the command-line input into an array of strings based on the `[hms]` regex. Uses the verbose built-in function `.AddSeconds()` to add (hours*3600, minutes*60, and seconds) to `(date 0)` a/k/a `Monday, January 1, 0001, 12:00:00 AM`, then feeds that into `-f` with formatting `HH:mm:ss` which will automatically convert it to 24-hour clock format and output it.

#### Example:

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\time-after-some-time.ps1 25h100m0s
02:40:00
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 104 bytes

```
h,m,s=io.read():match"(%d+)h(%d+)m(%d+)"m=m+s/60;print(("%02d:%02d:%02d"):format((h+m/60)%24,m%60,s%60))
```

Answer (score 1):

### VB.NET (107 bytes)

First submission for code golf so I'm guessing character count => byte count?

```
MsgBox(TimeSpan.Zero.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(Regex.Replace(InputBox("XhYmZs"),"[hm]",":").Trim("s"))).ToString)
```

Comment: https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 158

```
import re
e=input()
b=[];p=0
for s in re.split('\D',e)[:3][::-1]:c,a=divmod(int(s),60);b+=[a+p];p=c
b[2]=(b[2]+p)%24;f=':%02d'*3;print(f[1:]%(b[2],b[1],b[0]))
```

Ungolfed version:

```
import re
def timer(elapsed):
    base=[]
    previous_carry=0
    for section in re.split('\D+',elapsed)[:3][::-1]:
        carry,amount=divmod(int(section),60)
        base+=[amount+previous_carry]
        previous_carry=carry
    base[2]=(base[2]+previous_carry)%24
    format_str = ':%02d'*3
    return format_str[1:]%(base[2],base[1],base[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 50 bytes

```
0[l"hms"Ser~][24 60 60].{md}(;+2/::+{"%02d"e%}%':*
```

Answer (score 1):

## GNU sed+date, 51 bytes

(including +1 byte for `-r` flag)

```
#!/bin/sed -rf
s/(.*h)(.*m)(.*s)/date -d"0:0 \1our\2in\3ec" +%T/e
```

This simply gets `date` to add the specified number of hours, minutes and seconds to `00:00:00` (today) and display the time part.  Recommended to set `TZ=UTC` or avoid running the program around a local-time change (e.g. daylight savings).